# Не получается разделить строку в Powershell через кавычки

Tags: powershell

Доброй ночи,
есть большой файл **vpn.csv**, где строки имеют примерно такой вид:

```
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:56 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""user1"",""4""
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:51 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""john@notmydomain.com"",""4""
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:46 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""notmydomain\mary"",""4""
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:46 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""user"",""4""
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:44 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""john"",""4""
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:41 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""mydomain\myuser"",""4""
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:33 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""mydomain\user"",""4""
"Address assigned to session,""cisco asa 192.168.0.1"",""1"",""Oct 28, 2020, 3:27:26 PM"",""VPN In Progress"",""192.168.2.1"",""0"",""192.168.0.1"",""0"",""notmydomain\user"",""4"""
```

И есть файл **all_users_AD.txt** , в котором просто имена пользователей нашего домена.

Скриптом ниже пытаюсь найти vpn.csv только те строки, которые касаются только пользователей нашего домена.

```
$FileADUsers = $PSScriptRoot+'\all_users_AD.txt'
$FileVPNData = $PSScriptRoot+'\vpn.csv'

$ADUsers = Get-Content $FileADUsers

Get-Content $FileVPNData | ForEach-Object {
    $str = $_ -split '""'
    
    if ($ADUsers -match $str[17]) {
        $str
    }
}
```

шестая строка файла выдает ошибку:

```
выполняется разбор "mydomain\myuser" - Нераспознанная esc-последовательность \m.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Пока додумался только в каждой строке, перед поиском, с помощью replace поменять \ на явно не встречающуюся в исходном файле комбинацию символов, например "___".

```
$FileADUsers = $PSScriptRoot+'\all_users_AD.txt'
$FileVPNData = $PSScriptRoot+'\vpn.csv'

$ADUsers = Get-Content $FileADUsers

Get-Content $FileVPNData | ForEach-Object {
    $_ = $_ -replace '\\','___'

    $str = $_ -split '""'
    
    if ($ADUsers -match $str[17]) {
        $str
    }
}
```

Может туповато и медленно, но додумался только до этого, и вроде работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
param(
    [IO.FileInfo]$ADUsersListFileName = 'D:\tmp\ADUersList.txt',
    [IO.FileInfo]$processedFile = "D:\tmp\in.txt"
)

[string[]]$ADUsersArray = Get-Content $ADUsersListFileName
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($processedFile)
while($buffer = $reader.ReadLine()){
    if ([Linq.Enumerable]::Contains($ADUsersArray, ($buffer -split ',')[11].Trim('"'))){
        $buffer
    }
}
$reader.Close()
```

Comment: Я просто новенький в этом деле))))
Файл для меня большой, 500 тыс строк, поэтому захотелось как-то построчно пройтись, а не весь файл загружать в массив. Если реально можно весь файл в массив, а потом в другой массив, и сравнивать их между собой - я попробую в понедельник, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: не подумал как то про размер файла. исправил решение, вот так должно работать, надеюсь список ваших пользователей в массив можно засунуть.